# Чтение строки байт (b'') в python

Tags: python, udp

Друзья, хочу средствами python получать и декодировать данные из UDP потока.

Получать данные в строку байт не проблема, проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как ее раскодировать. Данные со смещением, то есть n-ое смещение байт имеет свою кодировку.

Я не понимаю, как мне правильно разделить байтовую строку (например по размеру) и декодировать это кусками.

Пример строки:

> b'F\x00jKT4\xb4'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb9\\xf1\xfb\xa5\x18\xa3\x16_\x01\xe8\x03\x93*\x06\x00\xbc@i"\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x80,\x05\xd0\x00\x00\x00\x00\xec\xd9\xef\xfb\xa5\x18\xa3\x16\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: Что такое `n-ое смещение байт ` ?

Comment: Там не просто текст отправляется, а бинарные данные с структурой? Когда игрался с TCP и сокетами, отправлял данные как `<8-байт указывающих длину сообщения><само сообщение>`. А у вас как будто данные, отравленные порцией, с добиванием в конце `\0`

Comment: Раскодировать во что? Формат у этого потока данных какой-нибудь есть?

Comment: Данные идут в строке байт, раскодировать байты, насколько я понял, надо в своей кодировке, она разная в каждом смещении. Про смещение - строка идет определенным размером, и если моя мысль верна, необходимо брать часть байтовой строки и раскодировать ее, но я не понимаю как разбить строку на байты

Comment: Чтобы было понятнее - вот документация того, что я хочу получать http://ftp.spbexchange.ru/TS/DOCS/MDbinary.pdf

Comment: Мистер @Zen. Уж коли вы приложили документация (и за это спасибо), пожалуйста "переделайте" свой вопрос согласно "2. Общая информация о протоколе".

Comment: А что это изменит? Меня интересовал не конкретный случай а общий принцип по которому раскодируют пакеты с данными в разной кодировке

Comment: Вопрос эквивалентен такому "как из массива байт выделить подмассив, т.е. часть массива с индекса x длиной у?" Если да, это делается так `myarra[x:x+y]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бгодаря [@Roman Konoval](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218971/roman-konoval) в целом разобрался как правильно читать и переводить данные из потока.

Взяв за переменную 'a' строку из изначального сообщения, можно, например получить:

```
len(list(a))  #общая длинна списка байт
list(a) #список байт
binascii.hexlify(bytes(a[12:20]) #HEX строка байт в конкретном смещении.
```

Далее из последнего можно преобразовать данные в читаемый вид. Это все, что требовалось в данном случае.

Comment: Чтобы получить длину набора байт, нет необходимости преобразовывать сначала в список. Просто пишите `len(a)`. Если a уже набор байт, нет необходимости преобразовывать его в список, потом обратно в байты, чтобы получить шестнадцатеричное представление - просто пишите `binascii.hexlify(a[12:20])`. К тому же строка `list(a)` никак не изменяет содержимое переменной `a`, а возвращает новый список, но вы этот список никак не используете.

Comment: @insolor Вы правы, спасибо за замечание